# Running celery group: where two tasks are run in parallel to get results to produce a third result

Tags: python, parallel-processing, celery

**How do I set it so that the dependent tasks are run in parallel (instead of sequentially) to reduce the overall execution time**

- I have the following "master" task below
- It is dependent on the *get_latest_close_price(symbol)* and *option_chain(symbol)* celery task results
- The master tasks transforms the results from these two tasks to produce the final pivot table
- The problem is that both these independent tasks talk to different API systems to get it's input (sometimes taking several seconds to execute)
- What I am noticing is that the order of the celery task in the group statement matters:

  - If *get_lastest_close_price* is first, it gets run before the *option_chain* (and vise versa)
  - To me it seems like these statements are being run sequentially instead of in parallel
  - Is my understanding wrong?

.

```
@celery.task(name='master_task')
def process_chain(symbol):

   # g = group(get_latest_close_price.s(symbol), option_chain.s(symbol))
   g = group(option_chain.s(symbol), get_latest_close_price.s(symbol))

   results = g()

   with result.allow_join_result():
       data = results.get()
       data = util_transform_option_chain(data[1], data[0])

   return({'result':data})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`group` will definitely run in parallel . . . if you have multiple workers or concurrency > 1.  But, just as an FYI--you may want to combine a [**`chord`**](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords) with `group` to handle the result the way that you want.

Comment: setting --concurrency=5 got me the result I was expecting

Comment: Is there a good tutorial/article to understand group, chord etc. I'm not sure if I understand the concepts fully...I'm sort of wingin' it